# Create script to delete files in subfolders

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, wildcards

Good afternoon,

I need to create a script to delete files older than 30 days from the Downloads folder for all users on a server.

I used the command below but it didn't work. Any idea what could be wrong?

```
Get-ChildItem "\\ server \ folder1 \ User_Data \ * \ Downloads \ *" -Recurse |
    Where-Object {($_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-30))} |
        Remove-Item -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

Comment: What's the output when you run the command? Does it give an error or does it run without error but not do what you're expecting?

Comment: No, it doesn't have any errors, it just doesn't delete the files

Comment: Is powershell a requirement? Do you have to use powershell? I could whip something up that does this using python in about 3 minutes

Comment: Leandro -- Give this a shot and tell me if it work.... `Get-ChildItem "\\server\folder1\User_Data\*\Downloads" -Directory | % {Get-ChildItem $_.FullName -Filter "*" | Where LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-30) | Remove-Item -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue;};` If so, I'll be happy to add as an answer that you can accept rather than in this comment area.

Comment: So break down the command! Does `Get-ChildItem` return files? Does your `Where-Object` limit the results? Trouble-shooting 101!

Comment: Looking at your code, it's probably the spaces in the path: `"\\ server \ folder1 \ User_Data \ * \ Downloads \ *"`

Comment: Regarding the removal of the files, I will be able to test only on Monday. When I run the command I will update the information here on the forum. Thanks all

Comment: @KeithMiller Yes, when I run the Get-ChildItem command without the Remove-Item parameter, I get the information correctly.

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't silence the error action of `Remove-`Item`. There's probably an error message with useful information...

Comment: Also explain why it didn't work, what exactly is not working? Is it not working at all 100%, just not deleting some files within certain subfolders or what. I also agree about removing the `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` as Keith mentioned in case that's hiding the error detail you need to see for further troubleshooting. It could be "Access Denied", etc. I provided you a similar script I used for something and the way I handled that so simply give it a try and see what your result may be afterwards. Have you already done so?

Answer (score 0):

So, what happens if you do this...?

```
Get-ChildItem 'D:\Test\Reference\New folder' -Recurse
<#
# Results

    Directory: D:\Test\Reference\New folder


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                                                          
----                -------------         ------ ----                                                                                                          
d-----        06-Mar-20     10:52                New folder (2)                                                                                                
-a----        10-Jan-20     17:59              0 awél.txt                                                                                                      
-a----        04-Jan-20     02:01             39 hello.bat                                                                                                     
-a----        04-Jan-20     01:43             44 hello.ps1                                                                                                     
-a----        04-Jan-20     02:16             64 mytest - Copy.txt                                                                                             
-a----        04-Jan-20     02:16             64 mytest.txt                                                                                                    


    Directory: D:\Test\Reference\New folder\New folder (2)


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                                                          
----                -------------         ------ ----                                                                                                          
-a----        10-Jan-20     17:59              0 awél.txt                                                                                                      
-a----        04-Jan-20     02:01             39 hello.bat                                                                                                     
-a----        04-Jan-20     01:43             44 hello.ps1                                                                                                     
-a----        04-Jan-20     02:16             64 mytest - Copy.txt                                                                                             
-a----        04-Jan-20     02:16             64 mytest.txt   
#>

Get-ChildItem 'D:\Test\Reference\New folder' -Recurse | 
Where-Object {($_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-1))} | 
Remove-Item -WhatIf

<#
# Results

What if: Performing the operation "Remove File" on target "D:\Test\Reference\New folder\awél.txt".
What if: Performing the operation "Remove File" on target "D:\Test\Reference\New folder\hello.bat".
What if: Performing the operation "Remove File" on target "D:\Test\Reference\New folder\hello.ps1".
What if: Performing the operation "Remove File" on target "D:\Test\Reference\New folder\mytest - Copy.txt".
What if: Performing the operation "Remove File" on target "D:\Test\Reference\New folder\mytest.txt".
What if: Performing the operation "Remove File" on target "D:\Test\Reference\New folder\New folder (2)\awél.txt".
What if: Performing the operation "Remove File" on target "D:\Test\Reference\New folder\New folder (2)\hello.bat".
What if: Performing the operation "Remove File" on target "D:\Test\Reference\New folder\New folder (2)\hello.ps1".
What if: Performing the operation "Remove File" on target "D:\Test\Reference\New folder\New folder (2)\mytest - Copy.txt".
What if: Performing the operation "Remove File" on target "D:\Test\Reference\New folder\New folder (2)\mytest.txt".
#>

Get-ChildItem 'D:\Test\Reference\New folder' -Recurse | 
Where-Object {($_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-1))} | 
Remove-Item -Confirm:$false -Force
Get-ChildItem 'D:\Test\Reference\New folder' -Recurse
<#
# Results
    Directory: D:\Test\Reference\New folder


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                                                          
----                -------------         ------ ----                                                                                                          
d-----        06-Mar-20     10:51                New folder (2) 
#>
```

Answer (score 0):

This would work better:

```
$Path = "\\server\folder1\User_Data\*\Downloads"
$Daysback = "-30"
$CurrentDate = Get-Date
$DatetoDelete = $CurrentDate.AddDays($Daysback)
Get-ChildItem $Path -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -lt $DatetoDelete } | Remove-Item
```